# Combine mixins with generics in node.js

Tags: typescript, generics, mixins

I'm working on a library where I would like to support some different extensions for the same library methods.
Here is my shorted mixins code just to give you an idea:

```
type Creator<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
class DefaultCreator {
        world:string[] = [];
        someMagic() {
            this.world.push("magic")
        }
        getWorldList() {
            return this.world;
        }
}

function PlantCreator<TBase extends Creator>(Base: TBase) {
    return class extends Base {
        private world = (<DefaultCreator><any>this).world;
        createPlant() {
            this.world.push("Plant")
        }
    };
}

function AnimalCreator<TBase extends Creator>(Base: TBase) {
    return class extends Base {
        private world = (<DefaultCreator><any>this).world;
        createDog() {
            this.world.push("Dog")
        }
    };
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
const MyWorld = AnimalCreator(PlantCreator(DefaultCreator));
const world = new MyWorld();
world.someMagic();
world.createPlant();
world.createDog();
```

My question is now how can I create an class with takes the "MyWorld" from above?

```
abstract class Playground {
    abstract createWorld(creator: DefaultCreator);
    play() {
        this.createWorld(new DefaultCreator());
    }
}
```

My idea is the implementation can use the framework features (here just play) and creates the world with the customized Creator (aka Builder). I tried generics, but that does not compile. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible. Since `MyWorld` is not a type it is more a strange type description.

When I let my idea specify the type I get this line:

```
const MyWorld: { new(): ({ world: string[]; createDog(): void } & any); prototype: { world: string[]; createDog(): void } } = AnimalCreator(PlantCreator(DefaultCreator));
```

My solution is to force the user by convention to create the instance by the user and return the `world` of my example.

I modified my playground so that I get this code:

```
abstract class Playground {
    abstract createWorld(): string[];
    play() {
        console.log("Creating world containing:");
        this.createWorld().forEach(item => console.log(`- ${item}`))
    }
}

class MyPlayground extends Playground {
    createWorld(): string[] {
        const world = new MyWorld();
        world.someMagic();
        world.createPlant();
        world.createDog();
        return world.getWorldList();
    }
}

new MyPlayground().play();
```

The output of the code above:

> Creating world containing:
>   - magic
>   - Plant
>   - Dog

Answer (score 1):

You actually weren't far off, but you blurred the lines between Types and Values. Fortunately, Javascript/Typescript lets you do this.

```js
// Match only a constructor
type Creator<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

// Match an actual class
interface CreatorClass<T> {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
}

class DefaultCreator {
        world:string[] = [];
        someMagic() {
            this.world.push("magic")
        }
        getWorldList() {
            return this.world;
        }
}

function PlantCreator<TBase extends Creator>(Base: TBase) {
    return class extends Base {
        private world = (<DefaultCreator><any>this).world;
        createPlant() {
            this.world.push("Plant")
        }
    };
}

function AnimalCreator<TBase extends Creator>(Base: TBase) {
    return class extends Base {
        private world = (<DefaultCreator><any>this).world;
        createDog() {
            this.world.push("Dog")
        }
    };
}

interface IPlantWorld {
    createPlant(): void;
}

interface IAnimalWorld {
  createDog();
}

const MyWorld: CreatorClass<IPlantWorld & IAnimalWorld> = AnimalCreator(PlantCreator(DefaultCreator));

abstract class Playground {
    // I want to have a reference of the class' constructor
    createOtherWorld<T>(creator: Creator<T>) {
        return new creator();
    }

    // I want to reference the class itself
    createWorld<T>(creator: CreatorClass<T>): T {
        return new creator() as T;
    }
    play() {
        this.createWorld(DefaultCreator);
    }
}



class EverythingPlaygroundFactory extends Playground {
    play() {
        // provide the type information
        return this.createWorld<IAnimalWorld & IPlantWorld>(MyWorld);
    }
}

let pg = new EverythingPlaygroundFactory();
let world = pg.createWorld(MyWorld);
world.createPlant();
world.createDog();

pg.createOtherWorld(MyWorld.prototype.constructor);
```

This is likely more along the lines of what you were looking for.

Something to note:

`type Creator<T = {}> = new (... args: any[]) => T` can and will only reference the actual constructor of any class, but will never match a whole class/class object. Always remember that classes/functions are executable objects.

Comment: You provide an interesting solution. So you put in an interface just an constructor to create new instances, right? If that is true: cool trick! However you missed that fact that Playground is an abstract class, each custom implementation should use its own creators. When I modify your `createWorld` function I cannot use the methods defined in `PlantCreator` nor `PlantCreator`. Is there also a solution?

Comment: I'll get back to you in a moment. Need to fiddle

Comment: That should solve the type issue. I strongly recommend reconsidering your design pattern though, as you're trying to meld factories and instances that a factory would create into one thing.

But one observation I made is that whenever you "can't see" a method in Intellisense, it is because there was no compile-time type information available. You can resolve this by defining the type information in an interface, and specifying that as the return type annotation.

Comment: Now you limited the Playground to plants, I cannot create animals. That is why I like the idea of mixins which provide some kind of polymorphism and decorators where I can call whatever I like on a single object. My example above was not very good as I see now.

Comment: I recommend rethinking your design. You're trying to have compile-time information that's created at runtime. If you want to meld types, you can use the `&` operator, which says "everything of both types is available in this one".

Comment: I've updated the code example to demonstrate melding types, and how to make `createDog` and `createPlant` accessible. You should be able to extrapolate everything you need to understand from the example now.

Comment: I updated my answer with the solution I had, just if you like to compare it. I reviewed your code again, this is an clear and out of my perspective classical way with interfaces, which are out of my view an overhead. I think I'll take my own solution. However you'll get my upvote, since I like the idea with the `&` operator.

Comment: Yes, that’s the better way to do it ☺️